# DIY for these plant hangers?

Tags: hardware, planting

I know this may be outside of the usual topics but here goes.

Is there a DIY for theses types of plant hangers? The one in the picture is $4 each, and with over 20 plants that would be at least $80 in plant hangers.
Is there some type of cheaper DIY for this?

I was considering L braces or corner brackets, but they’re more expensive than the $4 hanger.

Fyi: I’m cheap.

[image]

Comment: Make them from 3 bits of wood...

Comment: Is aesthetics a factor?

Comment: If your time is worth nothing and you can learn to use bending forks and have a welder, perhaps - depends on your cost of steel stock. If your time is worth anything, $80 for 20 of them is cheap. Quite possible you can't even buy the metal to make them for less than the finished object, due to economies of scale and supply chain costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot make an ornate painted metal wall bracket for "cheap", ie for considerably less than $4, using any process that I would call "DIY" in the context of hanging a plant.   If the question was "I have a metal shop, what's the cheapest approach to reproducing this piece", perhaps there would be a much-less-than-$4 one but that's not the question and this wouldn't be the forum.

A plant can be hung with a screw hook in a ceiling joist and a piece of string.  Total cost 50 cents.
[image]

If you need to hang it from a wall you can get offcut scraps of wood from a hardware store for free (or pick up a discarded flood-damaged piece of furniture off the street and use that for wood) and make wood L brackets.  You'll still need about 50 cents for screws.
[image]

Comment: Oh look, the 3 bits of wood as suggested...

Comment: You're getting free lumber? Especially these days with astronomical wood prices? Where?????

Answer (score 1):

I haven't priced flat steel stock, but you could make something triangular with no welding skill. You'd just need to drill 2 holes in the part that goes against the wall and an additional hole at the bottom of the hypotenuse. I'm still not sure you'll come in under 4 bucks, though.

[image]